# CakePHP Ajax Login System

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to create an ajax login script but have hit a wall. I hav built one before but now using the cakephp framwework. 
I'm not really sure ho to go about this. At the moment I have a login function in the controller,

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Do i then use ajax to send values to this from the form? These lines are from my old (non-cakephp) system,

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.site.com/login/",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("AttemptLogin=true&AccountEmail="+ userMail +"&AccountPassword=" + userPass);
```

Should i modify them in any way? Also, how do i handle any validations and login attempts with errorsetc.

Sorry about the question being quite open ended and long but i don't know where to go,I have looked for tutorials but can't find any.

Many Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript helper from cake and have one template that converts
the response to the json format, in the controller just include the helper:

```
var $helpers = array('Javascript');
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

//the template ie "/views/templates/ajax.ctp"
echo $javascript->object(isset($response) ? $response : array());
```

So yo can set you function like:

```
public function login()
{
  if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
     if($this->Auth->login()) {
        $response('success'=>true);
     } else {
        $response('success'=>false);
     }
   $this->set('response', $response);
   $this->render(null, 'ajax');
}
```

And the javascript i recommend jQuery

```
$.ajax({url:"/controller/login",type:"POST", data:$('#formLogin').serialize(), dataType:"json", success:responseLogin, context:this});

 function responseLogin(response)
 {
     //here is the object returned by cakephp
     if(!response.success)
        //do something the user don't login
     else
       //do something the user pass the login
 }
```